# NewSQL for data warehouses and spatial queries

Tags: data-warehouse, spatial-query, singlestore, voltdb

What NewSQL distributions are suited to dealing with data warehouses and spatial queries? (MemSQL, VoltDB, NuoDB, what? and why)

Answer (score 1):

MemSQL can handle data warehousing using disk-based columnstores (https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.7/columnstore/) for fact tables because they can handle very large tables with fast distributed joins (https://www.memsql.com/blog/6-5-performance/) and star joins (https://www.memsql.com/blog/performance-for-memsql-67/). And it can handle  geospatial (https://www.memsql.com/content/geospatial/) types and indexing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these databases have a free to use or free to tryout version. MemSQL has a free to use version for up to 128gb ram (https://www.memsql.com/blog/announcing-memsql-free-tier/). I should note I work at MemSQL :-).